# Oracle trigger instead of and rowcount

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, ado.net

I need to create insert and update triggers for view. I also need that sql%rowcount after executing insert/update on one row return 1. In SQL Server I can set nocount to on, then make some operations and then set nocount to off and select one row. How can I do something similar in Oracle.

I need this for mapping that view in NHibernate which expect Affected rows equal 1.

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure that an update will only affect one row is to create a primary key or a unique constraint on the table. Then use the columns that make up the constraint in the where clause of your update statement.

Comment: Ok, but in my trigger I need modify multiple rows from multiple tables.